# How do I extend a class to override a single imported class?

Tags: php, oop, overriding

Let's say I have something like this:

```php
class Bar {
    // some code here
}
```

```php
use class Bar;
class Foo {
    public function someFunction() {
        $barrel = new Bar();
        // some code here
    }
}
```

I need to completely override the `Bar` class and name it `CustomBar`. Is there a way to extend the class `Foo` just to make it use `CustomBar` in each case?

Comment: Can you change `Foo`?

Comment: @Barmar, technically yes, but it's a class maintained by the vendor and it will be reset with each update. So the goal is to make an extension to override some core functionality.

Comment: That's too bad. I was going to suggest that you define a method `getBar()`, and replace all calls to `new Bar()` with `self::getBar()`. Then `CustomFoo` can override the `getBar()` method to use `new CustomBar()`.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do what you want without redesigning `Foo` to be extensible like this.

Comment: Extend foo it self? Depency injection possible?

Comment: Unless the package (or the framework itself you use, if `Foo` is some kind of service) allows for this, you can't do this with the code provided in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do this without redesigning `Foo` itself which is possible but since `Foo` is being maintained by the vendor each update will revert it.
Thanks to @Barmar.